# Chaining PartialFunctions with andThen in Scala

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Let us reuse examples from Daily scala :

```
type PF = PartialFunction[Int,Int]

val pf1 : PF = {case 1 => 2}                      

val pf2 : PF = {case 2 => 3}
```

and let us add:

```
val pf3 : PF = {case 3 => 4}
```

andThen works as expected here:

```
pf1 andThen pf2 isDefinedAt(x)
```

returns `true` iff `x == 1` (actually, `pf2` does not need to be a PartialFunction at all)

However, I expected that:

```
pf1 andThen pf3 isDefinedAt(x)
```

would return `false` for all `x` (i.e., iff pf1 is defined, check for pf3), but it does not and only validates pf1.

In the end, `pf1 andThen pf3 lift(x)` always result in a MatchError. I would prefer to get None… I can obtain this behavior by lifting each function such as in `pf1.lift(x).flatMap(pf3.lift)` but is there any easier way using pure PartialFunction API? (and without lifting each partial function individually?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at `andThen`:

```
def andThen[C](k: (B) => C): PartialFunction[A, C]
```

This composes the receiver with *a function* and not a *partial function*. That is, `k` is expected to be fully defined, it doesn't have `isDefinedAt`. Therefore, the resulting partial function does not need to alter the behaviour of `isDefinedAt`, it will still just has to consult the first partial function.

You could write your own extension that composes two partial functions:

```
implicit class ComposePartial[A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]) {
  def collect[C](that: PartialFunction[B, C]): PartialFunction[A, C] =
    new PartialFunction[A, C] {
      def apply(a: A): C = that(pf(a))
      def isDefinedAt(a: A) = pf.isDefinedAt(a) && {
        val b = pf(a)
        that.isDefinedAt(b)
      }
    }
}

pf1 collect pf2 isDefinedAt(1)  // true
pf1 collect pf3 isDefinedAt(1)  // false
```

The problem is that you have to invoke `pf(a)`, so given that Scala doesn't enforce purity, you may end up executing side effects unwantedly.

Comment: I try this, but all `apply` and `isDefinedAt` colled twice.

Answer (score 7):

You need the equivalent of `flatMap` for `PartialFunction`s.

```
implicit class CollectPartial[A, B](f: PartialFunction[A, B]) {
    def collect[C](g: PartialFunction[B, C]) = Function.unlift { a: A =>
        f.lift(a).flatMap(g.lift)
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
val a: PartialFunction[String, Int] = ...
val b: PartialFunction[Int, Char] = ...
val c: PartialFunction[String, Char] = a collect b
```

This works as expected even with side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply :

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: PartialFunction[A, B], g: PartialFunction[B, C]) : PartialFunction[A, C] =
Function.unlift(f.andThen(g.lift))
```