# Scala function composition totalFn(partialFn(totalFn(x)))

Tags: scala, partialfunction, partial-functions

I was trying to compose three functions with only the middle one being a PartialFunction. I would expect the resulting type to be PartialFunction as well.

Example:

```
val mod10: Int => Int = _ % 10
val inverse: PartialFunction[Int, Double] = { case n if n != 0 => 1.0 / n }
val triple: Double => Double = _ * 3

val calc: Int => Double = mod10 andThen inverse andThen triple
```

However, `calc` is not defined on the whole of its domain. It will throw MatchError for every number divisible by 10.

What is the reason for returning a total function when at least one of the functions in the composition is partial?

Another example where composition of partial functions results in another partial function with incorrect domain conditions:

```
val inverse: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = { case n if n != 0 => 1.0 / n }
val arcSin: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = { 
   case n if math.abs(n) <= 1 => math.asin(n)
}

val calc: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = inverse andThen arcSin
```

I would expect the domain of `calc` to be `(-Infinity, -1] union [1, Infinity)` but calling `calc.lift(0.5)` will throw a MathError instead of returning `None` because the input is within the first function's domain.

Thanks,
Norbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Example 1: What is the reason for returning a total function when at least one of the functions in the composition is partial?

It's because the first function in your first example is a total function (Function1) and its [andThen](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/Function1.html#andThen[A](g:R=%3EA):T1=%3EA) method returns a Function1 regardless of whether the second function is total or partial:

```
def andThen[A](g: (R) => A): (T1) => A
```

My guess is that the Scala language design team prefers a more generalized returned value since [PartialFunction is a subclass of Function](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/PartialFunction.html) and would rather let users derive specialized code as needed.

> Example 2: calling calc.lift(0.5) will throw a MathError instead of returning None

From the [PartialFunction API doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/PartialFunction.html#andThen[C](k:B=%3EC):PartialFunction[A,C]),  composing two partial functions via `andThen` will return a partial function with the same domain as the first partial function:

```
 def andThen[C](k: (B) => C): PartialFunction[A, C]
```

Thus, the resultant composed function disregards the fact that `inverse(0.5)` (i.e. 2.0) is outside the domain of the second partial function `arcSin`.

---

**So, when composing a function (total or partial) with a partial function using `andThen`, how can we make it return a partial function with proper domain?**

Similar to what's demonstrated in this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024626/compose-partial-functions), one can enhance `andThen` via a couple of implicit classes to restrict the domain of the resultant composed function to a subset of the first function's domain that return values within the partial function's domain:

```
object ComposeFcnOps {
  implicit class TotalCompose[A, B](f: Function[A, B]) {
    def andThenPartial[C](that: PartialFunction[B, C]): PartialFunction[A, C] =
      Function.unlift(x => Option(f(x)).flatMap(that.lift))
  }

  implicit class PartialCompose[A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]) {
    def andThenPartial[C](that: PartialFunction[B, C]): PartialFunction[A, C] =
      Function.unlift(x => pf.lift(x).flatMap(that.lift))
  }
}
```

Testing with the example functions:

```
import ComposeFcnOps._

val mod10: Int => Int = _ % 10
val inverse1: PartialFunction[Int, Double] = { case n if n != 0 => 1.0 / n }
val triple: Double => Double = _ * 3

val calc1 = mod10 andThenPartial inverse1 andThen triple
// calc1: PartialFunction[Int,Double] = <function1>

calc1.isDefinedAt(0)
// res1: Boolean = false

val inverse2: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = { case n if n != 0 => 1.0 / n }
val arcSin: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = { 
   case n if math.abs(n) <= 1 => math.asin(n)
}

val calc2 = inverse2 andThenPartial arcSin
// calc2: PartialFunction[Double,Double] = <function1>

calc2.isDefinedAt(0.5)
// res2: Boolean = false

calc2.lift(0.5)
// res3: Option[Double] = None
```

Comment: Thanks Leo! This would be a great extension to the language :) I'll definitely start using this.

Comment: FYI @norbertk, I've expanded the answer to also cover the case of composing a total function with a partial function using `andThen`.

Comment: After reading your first post, I created a class which included both andThen and compose. I just didn't think of creating implicit classes to solve this problem but it's a good way of adding missing functionality. 

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is your only expecting non-zero value.

```
{ case n if n != 0 => 1.0 / n }
```

then what if it will equal to zero then that is the cause of match Error..

```
{ 
   case n if n != 0 => 1.0 / n   // non-zero value.
   case n if n == 0 =>           // zero value.

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rex for the reply. I know where the MatchError comes from. The problem is not that it gets thrown but that the result type is not a PartialFunction, i.e. I cannot use `.lift` to convert the result to `Option[T]`. There is no meaningful default value and the final function `calc` should throw a MatchError.

Comment: def calc(x: Int)(a: PartialFunction[Int, Double])(c: Double)  = mod10 andThen inverse andThen triple

Comment: Is it possible to use something like this ?

Comment: I don't think that code means what you want it to mean. What are the second two parameters doing (`a` and `c`)?

Answer (score 1):

`andThen` is defined on `Function1`, and simply isn't designed to compose partial functions. Therefore, I recommend lifting them to total functions before using it.

```
val calc = Function.unlift(mod10 andThen inverse.lift andThen (_.map(triple)))
```

And

```
val calc = Function.unlift(inverse.lift andThen (_.flatMap(arcSin.lift)))
```